# Can you make a bump map using grey scale after you texture paint?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm working on an apple model and am about to texture it. I plan on using bump maps, reflection maps, etc. My only problem is that it would be much easier for me to texture paint the apple instead of using an image or such. What I was wondering if it's possible to turn the texture painting I do on the apple into a bump map using grey scale, or do I need to use an image directly?

Comment: of course you can paint on your object, then export the image you've created and make it a bump map with a soft like CrazyBump or else

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to directly paint your bump maps and view it real time.

Its a little hard to see in the GIF but works perfect close up.

[image]

Here is a flat plane (Not subdived).

[image]

This is the render view

[image]

Just make a new image texture and make sure it is set to 50% grey, So when you paint white it bumps up and black bumps down. 
[image]

[image]

This is what the image texture looked like after painting. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a direct way to bump map, but texture painting in grayscale is technically bumpmapping. In your material you can use an Image Texture Node to read your painted bump map. You can then feed this (non-color) value into something like the Cycles Bump Node which can take a height value, which will generate a normal map. Alternatively you could use displacement (in the material itself) to directly move the vertices in render mode. I have personally used these methods in Cycles.